# Application's view only in portrait : android

Tags: android

i'm trying to create an android application. i want that application's view should be only in portrait..Mean if i move my mobile in landscape so application should not be change as it should remain in constant as portrait.
I'll be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or (seeing as it was asked for portrait, not landscape)

```
<activity android:name=".IntroHome"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"  
       >
</activity>
```

You can also do this in the main java code with:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Manifest to this:

```
<activity android:name=".IntroHome"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"  
           >
</activity>
```

Comment: should be "portrait" instead of "landscape"